# Mac won’t boot on safe mode

Tags: macos

I’m on a MacBook Air running on High Sierra 10.13.6. I’ve had some trouble with it and usually been able to find solutions for it but one of the common trouble shooters is to boot into safe mode which it doesn’t seem to want to do... I have noticed this has happened since I previously enabled FireVault then turned it off and have a feeling that might have something to do with it. If anyone has any information or can point me to any resources that would be great!

Ps- I do realize the end solution should be to wipe and do a fresh install eventually, just trying to make sure I have everything I need backed up off of it first while also increasing my knowledge of the MacOS system!

Comment: If you have recently flipped FileVault on or off you should probably let that operation finish before making more changes.  IIRC you can see the staus of the conversion in SystemPreferences -> Security

Comment: I did. That was months ago. But I have a weird feeling that may contribute to the cause of this issue from reading others’ issues with firevault.

Comment: Could be.  If you haven't seen this [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) it might help

Comment: I was thinking about your problem and you indicated that "your having trouble with it" but there isn't a detail of the issues your seeing.  Have you done a hardware diagnostic on the system to see if there are issues.  You can start your Mac by holding down the <key>D</key> and run through the diagnostics.  Might help narrow some things down.  If you can describe specific issue we might be able to dig in to it with you.